# how to add to svn all *.class files from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have java project in eclipse. And sync in svn.

[image: Java project]

In navigator view I see not sync class files. How to add all *.class files for upload to svn:

[image: classes]

Comment: Why do you want to add your compiled code to the repository? Usual practice is to only store the resources required to build things in the repository, as your build process should be consistent enough to reproduce the correct class files, and you won't ever have a set of class files that don't match the checked-in source files.

Comment: This is called "source control" for a reason. This is for SOURCE files.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've got a specific justification for wanting to store your compiled code in version control, I wouldn't bother trying to add `.class` files. Eclipse *may* allow you to add them somehow, but if it does it probably intentionally makes it difficult. There's no reason why you couldn't add them manually from a command line, though.

Instead, I would ensure that your build scripts (ant, maven or whatever) are checked into the repository, and build your class files in a deterministic and repeatable way. Ensure the version of the compiler is specified, for example, so that the current version of your compiler becomes a requirement for repeating the build using this source code at this moment in time.